# FineUploader CSV Header Validation

Tags: csv, fine-uploader

I have looked through the FineUploader documentation and wanted to ask the community just in case I missed it. Need to allow users to upload a CSV file but would like to check the headers in the CSV to make sure they match what is required. Is that a way to do this within FineUploader settings?

For instance, making sure a CSV that a user uploads has column headers of First Name, Last Name, Address, Phone. If it doesn't match those column headers then return an error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This type of custom validation is *exactly* why [custom validation](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html) callbacks were added to Fine Uploader a while back. In your case, since you need access to the `File` or `Blob`, you can contribute [an `onSubmit` callback](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) that returns a `Promise`. In this callback, you can determine if the file is a CSV. If it is, you can read the file client-side using [`FileReader`](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api), parsing the file to determine if it conforms to your requirements. If it does, simply fulfill the returned promise. Otherwise, reject it. Note that you can get access to the underlying `File` or `Blob`, given the file ID, via the [`getFile` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getFile).

Comment: Thanks Ray for the explanation. By `Promise` you mean returning `true` or `false` right?

Comment: No, I mean a [`Promise` instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Reading a file is an async operation - you can't simply return `false` or `true` since your callback handler will return before the file read operation is complete. Fine Uploader accepts promissory (also referred to as "thenable") return values for [a number of callbacks](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/async-tasks-and-promises.html).